# "ERROR: syntax: cannot juxtapose string literal" when ending a triple-quoted string literal with a quote

Tags: julia

I'm trying to create a string literal representing a CSV file with quoted fields. The intended CSV looks like this:

```
"a","b"
"1","2"
```

Triple quotes work if I want a newline character at the end of the string:

```
julia> """
       "a","b"
       "1","2"
       """
"\"a\",\"b\"\n\"1\",\"2\"\n"
```

But if I try to make a string without the newline character at the end, then I get a syntax error:

```
julia> """
       "a","b"
       "1","2""""
ERROR: syntax: cannot juxtapose string literal
```

Is there a simple way to get around this?

As an aside, note that there is no syntax error when you start the string-literal with a quote:

```
julia> """"a","b"
       "1","2"
       """
"\"a\",\"b\"\n\"1\",\"2\"\n"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that this by itself is a valid string literal:

```
"""
"a","b"
"1","2"""
```

When you follow that with another `"` the parser thinks "woah, you can’t just follow a string with another string". You can force it to not consider the quote after `2` as part of a closing `"""` sequence by escaping it with `\`:

```
"""
"a","b"
"1","2\""""
```

At the start of the string, there's no such issue since the first three `"` characters are taken to start a string literal and the following `"` must just be a quote character inside of the string, which is what you want.

I'm not sure what you would consider the best solution to be. The options are:

1. Escape the `"` at the end;
2. Put the closing `"""` on a separate line.

The latter seems better to me, but it's your call.

See the [Julia Docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#Triple-Quoted-String-Literals-1) for other examples on Triple-Quoted String Literals.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Truthfully, the newline character at the end of the string is fine for what I need right now, but I was wondering how I would do it if I didn't want the newline.